# IDE / language for Okuma machine tool control development

Tags: okuma

I'm trying to set up some new developers to make apps for the Okuma control using the Okuma API and SDK. What environment should they use? I tried installing Visual Studio Express 2012 but it keeps giving an error looking for files during install. Also, what language should they use so they can work with the Okuma API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Okuma API is written using .NET 4.0 so you really have several options.

Normally I'd say [Visual Studio express 2012 for desktop](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9816758) is best but I've seen problems putting it on Windows XP.

If you're using windows XP and aren't ready to invest in a full version of Visual Studio yet, I'd recommend [Visual C# Express 2010](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9709939). If you're more familiar with VB and don't want to switch, do the VB express verison.

All these (and the professional version) are available from
www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng#downloads

Answer (score 1):

VS 2019 community edition is currently working fine for me doing this. I just have to choose which .net framework in the project settings. That was not listed in the prior answer in case anyone comes across this in the future.